# "Vintage" Apple stickers

Tags: history

Cleaning out my mother's basement, I found a "sticker album" that I kept as a child in the early 80s. A few pages of my sticker album contain these stickers -- maybe 12 in all -- all still attached to their backing and probably still "stickable":
[image]

Unfortunately, I don't remember where or when I got them.

I found it particularly unusual that the bottom "stripe" was so offset from the upper part of the apple and I'm not sure if that is a misprint or a deliberate evolution of the logo.

Can anyone tell me about these stickers and when they might have been released? It might have been before the Mac came out, but the same sticker album also contained a "Where's the Beef?" sticker which was the famous Wendy's ad campaign in 1984, the same year the Mac was released.
Do they have any value beyond nostalgia and hipsterism?

Comment: Those stickers were generally over printed. If you could get a better focused / lit picture of one decal, you might see that the area that peels away - leaving just the apple + leaf + name from the backing is likely to be printed properly.

Comment: I will try to get a better picture, or at least take a closer look. I was rifling through a whole lot of stuff at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the very first stickers and logos introduced by Apple Inc. when the Apple II was shipped in 1977.
The font-face used here is called **Motter Tektura** and the WikiPedia info can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography_of_Apple_Inc.).

The logo itself is not a misprint, but as you can see on [this image](http://www.vintagecomputing.com/wp-content/images/retroscan/apple_sticker_large.jpg) can be removed from the foil with a result a nice Apple (which is still used by Apple).

ps. can I have one? :-)

Comment: I don't know about "have", but I might be willing to sell you one for little more than the price of shipping.